# How to keep persistent data in a function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, closures

I have a function that receives a number from 1 to 999. I want to know if this number has changed since the last time the function was called.

For example, if I called it in this order, its expected behaviour would be:

- hasUpdated(1) // output false
- hasUpdated (2) // output true
- hasUpdated(1) // output true (because I've switched to 2 before, so
  the number has been updated).

I wrote the following closure function:

```js
const hasUpdated = (data) => {
  let updated = false;
  function checkIfUpdated (data){
    if(updated){
      return true
    }
    if(!updated && data > 1){
      updated= true
      return true
    }
    if (!updated && data === 1) {
      return false 
    }
  }
  checkIfUpdated(data)
}
```

Its result is:

- hasUpdated(1)  // output false
- hasUpdated (2) // output true
- hasUpdated(1) // output false

So there it doesn't doesn't properly save the value. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new closure and a new `updated` variable every time you call `hasUpdated`. What you need to do for keeping a persistent variable is create the closure only once. Also you will need to keep the `data` of the last call to compare to, not just an `updated` flag.

```
function makeUpdateTest(initialValue) {
  let oldData = initialValue;
  return (newData) => {
    const updated = newData !== oldData;
    oldData = newData;
    return updated;
  };
}

const hasUpdated = makeUpdateTest(1);
console.log(hasUpdated(1)) // false
console.log(hasUpdated(2)) // true
console.log(hasUpdated(2)) // false
console.log(hasUpdated(1)) // true
```

A `hasUpdated2 = makeUpdateTest()` would keep a separate state.